# Disable line breaks after method arguments in Rider

Tags: c#, rider, editorconfig

Whenever I let JetBrains Rider reformat my code, it replaces

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadAsync([FromQuery] string path, [FromQuery] string disposition = "attachment")
{
    // ...
}
```

with

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadAsync([FromQuery]
                                               string path, [FromQuery]
                                               string disposition = "attachment")
{
    // ...
}
```

which looks really strange. How can I disable this?

My Rider Code-Style Settings are reset to default and my .editorconfig looks like this:

```
root = true

[*]
charset                  = utf-8-bom
end_of_line              = lf
indent_style             = space
insert_final_newline     = true
indent_size              = 4
trim_trailing_whitespace = true

[*.sln]
indent_style = tab

[*.{csproj,vbproj,vcxproj,vcxproj.filters,proj,projitems,shproj}]
indent_size = 2

[*.{json,xml,yml,config,props,targets,nuspec,resx,ruleset,vsixmanifest,vsct}]
indent_size = 2

[*.{cs,csx,cake,vb}]
dotnet_sort_system_directives_first                                          = true
dotnet_style_coalesce_expression                                             = true
dotnet_style_collection_initializer                                          = true
dotnet_style_explicit_tuple_names                                            = true
dotnet_style_null_propagation                                                = true
dotnet_style_object_initializer                                              = true
dotnet_style_predefined_type_for_locals_parameters_members                   = true
dotnet_style_predefined_type_for_member_access                               = true
dotnet_style_qualification_for_event                                         = false
dotnet_style_qualification_for_field                                         = false
dotnet_style_qualification_for_method                                        = false
dotnet_style_qualification_for_property                                      = false

dotnet_naming_symbols.constant_fields.applicable_kinds                       = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.constant_fields.required_modifiers                     = const
dotnet_naming_symbols.non_private_readonly_fields.applicable_accessibilities = public, internal, protected
dotnet_naming_symbols.non_private_readonly_fields.applicable_kinds           = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.non_private_readonly_fields.required_modifiers         = readonly
dotnet_naming_symbols.static_readonly_fields.applicable_kinds                = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.static_readonly_fields.required_modifiers              = static, readonly
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_readonly_fields.applicable_accessibilities     = private
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_readonly_fields.applicable_kinds               = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_readonly_fields.required_modifiers             = readonly
dotnet_naming_symbols.public_internal_fields.applicable_accessibilities      = public, internal
dotnet_naming_symbols.public_internal_fields.applicable_kinds                = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_protected_fields.applicable_accessibilities    = private, protected
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_protected_fields.applicable_kinds              = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.public_symbols.applicable_accessibilities              = public, internal, protected, protected_internal
dotnet_naming_symbols.public_symbols.applicable_kinds                        = method, property, event, delegate
dotnet_naming_symbols.parameters.applicable_kinds                            = parameter
dotnet_naming_symbols.non_interface_types.applicable_kinds                   = class, struct, enum, delegate
dotnet_naming_symbols.interface_types.applicable_kinds                       = interface

dotnet_naming_style.camel_case.capitalization                                = camel_case
dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case.capitalization                               = pascal_case
dotnet_naming_style.first_upper.capitalization                               = first_word_upper
dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case_with_i_prefix.capitalization                 = pascal_case
dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case_with_i_prefix.required_prefix                = I
dotnet_naming_style.camel_case_with_lodash_prefix.capitalization             = camel_case
dotnet_naming_style.camel_case_with_lodash_prefix.required_prefix            = _

dotnet_naming_rule.constant_fields_must_be_pascal_case.severity              = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.constant_fields_must_be_pascal_case.symbols               = constant_fields
dotnet_naming_rule.constant_fields_must_be_pascal_case.style                 = pascal_case
dotnet_naming_rule.non_private_readonly_fields_must_be_pascal_case.severity  = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.non_private_readonly_fields_must_be_pascal_case.symbols   = non_private_readonly_fields
dotnet_naming_rule.non_private_readonly_fields_must_be_pascal_case.style     = pascal_case
dotnet_naming_rule.static_readonly_fields_must_be_pascal_case.severity       = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.static_readonly_fields_must_be_pascal_case.symbols        = static_readonly_fields
dotnet_naming_rule.static_readonly_fields_must_be_pascal_case.style          = pascal_case
dotnet_naming_rule.private_readonly_fields_must_be_camel_case.severity       = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.private_readonly_fields_must_be_camel_case.symbols        = private_readonly_fields
dotnet_naming_rule.private_readonly_fields_must_be_camel_case.style          = camel_case_with_lodash_prefix
dotnet_naming_rule.public_internal_fields_must_be_pascal_case.severity       = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.public_internal_fields_must_be_pascal_case.symbols        = public_internal_fields
dotnet_naming_rule.public_internal_fields_must_be_pascal_case.style          = pascal_case
dotnet_naming_rule.private_protected_fields_must_be_camel_case.severity      = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.private_protected_fields_must_be_camel_case.symbols       = private_protected_fields
dotnet_naming_rule.private_protected_fields_must_be_camel_case.style         = camel_case_with_lodash_prefix
dotnet_naming_rule.public_members_must_be_capitalized.severity               = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.public_members_must_be_capitalized.symbols                = public_symbols
dotnet_naming_rule.public_members_must_be_capitalized.style                  = first_upper
dotnet_naming_rule.parameters_must_be_camel_case.severity                    = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.parameters_must_be_camel_case.symbols                     = parameters
dotnet_naming_rule.parameters_must_be_camel_case.style                       = camel_case
dotnet_naming_rule.non_interface_types_must_be_pascal_case.severity          = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.non_interface_types_must_be_pascal_case.symbols           = non_interface_types
dotnet_naming_rule.non_interface_types_must_be_pascal_case.style             = pascal_case
dotnet_naming_rule.interface_types_must_be_prefixed_with_i.severity          = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.interface_types_must_be_prefixed_with_i.symbols           = interface_types
dotnet_naming_rule.interface_types_must_be_prefixed_with_i.style             = pascal_case_with_i_prefix

[*.{cs,csx,cake}]
csharp_max_line_length                                                   = 180

csharp_indent_block_contents                                             = true
csharp_indent_braces                                                     = false
csharp_indent_case_contents                                              = true
csharp_indent_labels                                                     = no_change
csharp_indent_switch_labels                                              = true

csharp_style_conditional_delegate_call                                   = true
csharp_style_expression_bodied_accessors                                 = true
csharp_style_expression_bodied_constructors                              = false
csharp_style_expression_bodied_indexers                                  = true
csharp_style_expression_bodied_methods                                   = true
csharp_style_expression_bodied_operators                                 = true
csharp_style_expression_bodied_properties                                = true
csharp_style_inlined_variable_declaration                                = true
csharp_style_pattern_matching_over_as_with_null_check                    = true
csharp_style_pattern_matching_over_is_with_cast_check                    = true
csharp_style_throw_expression                                            = true
csharp_style_var_elsewhere                                               = false
csharp_style_var_for_built_in_types                                      = false
csharp_style_var_when_type_is_apparent                                   = true

csharp_new_line_before_open_brace                                        = accessors, control_blocks, events, indexers, local_functions, methods, properties, types
csharp_new_line_before_catch                                             = true
csharp_new_line_before_else                                              = true
csharp_new_line_before_finally                                           = true
csharp_new_line_before_members_in_anonymous_types                        = true
csharp_new_line_before_members_in_object_initializers                    = true
csharp_new_line_between_query_expression_clauses                         = true

csharp_space_after_cast                                                  = false
csharp_space_after_colon_in_inheritance_clause                           = true
csharp_space_after_comma                                                 = true
csharp_space_after_dot                                                   = false
csharp_space_after_keywords_in_control_flow_statements                   = true
csharp_space_after_semicolon_in_for_statement                            = true
csharp_space_around_binary_operators                                     = before_and_after
csharp_space_around_declaration_statements                               = do_not_ignore
csharp_space_before_colon_in_inheritance_clause                          = true
csharp_space_before_comma                                                = false
csharp_space_before_dot                                                  = false
csharp_space_before_semicolon_in_for_statement                           = false
csharp_space_before_open_square_brackets                                 = false
csharp_space_between_empty_square_brackets                               = false
csharp_space_between_method_declaration_name_and_open_parenthesis        = false
csharp_space_between_method_declaration_parameter_list_parentheses       = false
csharp_space_between_method_declaration_empty_parameter_list_parentheses = false
csharp_space_between_method_call_name_and_opening_parenthesis            = false
csharp_space_between_method_call_parameter_list_parentheses              = false
csharp_space_between_method_call_empty_parameter_list_parentheses        = false
csharp_space_between_parentheses                                         = expressions
csharp_space_between_square_brackets                                     = false
csharp_space_within_parentheses                                          = false

csharp_keep_existing_attribute_arrangement                               = false
csharp_place_attribute_on_same_line                                      = false
csharp_place_type_attribute_on_same_line                                 = false
csharp_place_method_attribute_on_same_line                               = false
csharp_place_accessorholder_attribute_on_same_line                       = false
csharp_place_accessor_attribute_on_same_line                             = false
csharp_place_field_attribute_on_same_line                                = false

csharp_preserve_single_line_blocks                                       = true
csharp_preserve_single_line_statements                                   = false

csharp_prefer_simple_default_expression                                  = true
csharp_prefer_braces                                                     = false

csharp_braces_for_ifelse                                                 = required_for_complex
csharp_braces_for_for                                                    = required_for_complex
csharp_braces_for_foreach                                                = required_for_complex
csharp_braces_for_while                                                  = required_for_complex
csharp_braces_for_dowhile                                                = true
csharp_braces_for_using                                                  = required_for_complex
csharp_braces_for_lock                                                   = required_for_complex
csharp_braces_for_fixed                                                  = required_for_complex
csharp_braces_redundant                                                  = true

csharp_method_or_operator_body                                           = expression_body
csharp_local_function_body                                               = expression_body
csharp_constructor_or_destructor_body                                    = expression_body
csharp_accessor_owner_body                                               = expression_body
csharp_use_heuristics_for_body_style                                     = true

csharp_empty_block_style                                                 = together_same_line
csharp_keep_existing_embedded_arrangement                                = false
csharp_place_simple_embedded_statement_on_same_line                      = false
```

I'm searching for the right editorconfig-property to disable this for hours and played around with multiple other settings, but I didn't find the right one.

Setting all the `csharp_place_attribute` properties to `true` didn't have an effect either.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the cause for that. `csharp_max_attribute_length_for_same_line` is 0 by default, so setting it to a higher value solves the problem:

```
csharp_max_attribute_length_for_same_line = 80
```